# Is there a clean way to remove entries from grub.cfg

Tags: boot, grub2

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 as my promary system. I do have a testbed 22.04.
I have two NAS units that host files that need extra survivability.
For an ancillary reason, that is likely irrelevant at this point, I had to run update_grub.
Unfortunately on those two NAS units there are ISCSI targets which have legacy luns of specialized configurations. What happened is update-grub picked up these images as bootable systems, which they aren't as they require virsh.

I'd like to remove the erroneous images from the boot menu.
UEFI dutifully thinks there are 3 bootable entries, Ubuntu 20.04, Windows, Ubuntu 22.04.
I believe that is because it sees only the local drives whereas grub surveys remotely mounted luns.
Under the category of Ubuntu it lists every Linux boot system that was scanned.

Comment: Just remove them from grub.cfg ( as root ). When you do an update-grub again they will appear again. Then just remove them again.

Comment: Look at grub.cfg and determine which section they are in (probably 30_os-prober) and just make 30_os-prober non-executable. Then rerun update-grub (which gets run every kernel update, so this need be done only once).

Comment: Thank you guys for responding! I have an aversion to editing a Linux system file where literally the first line says " DO NOT EDIT". I thought turning off the execute bit in permissions was interesting except there were entries in 30_os_prober that were legit

Answer (score 1):

This may not work in all cases but occurred to me last night while pondering.

```
sudo iscsiadm -m node --logoutall=all
sudo update-grub
sudo iscsiadm -m node --logininall=all
```

In doing this all the system images due to them being created in virt-manager were rendered non-present.
update-grub only saw legitimate system bootable images after which I logged them all back in again. Now the boot menu shows only physically bootable devices, nvme, HDD, SSD